# Union of sigma-algebras

Tags: probability, measure-theory

While reading the book "Probability and Stochastics" by Ehran Çinlar, I have come across the following question in one of the early sections of the book.

**Q :** If $\varepsilon_{i} $ is a sigma-algebra for every $i \in I$ (countable or not) then  $\varepsilon_{I}=\bigvee_{i \in I} \varepsilon_{i} $ denotes the sigma algebra generated by $\bigcup_{i \in I} \varepsilon_{i}$.

Let $C$ be the collection of all sets $A$ having the form:

$$A=\bigcap_{i\in J} A_{i}$$

for some finite subset of $I$ , and sets $A_{i} \subset\varepsilon_{i}$, $i \in J$. Show that $C$ contains all $\varepsilon_{i}$ and therefore $\bigcup_{i \in I} \varepsilon_{i} $. Also show that $C$ is a $p$-system.

Answer (score 1):

First assertion follows by considering the definition of $C$ with $J=\{i\}$.

Second statement is immediate consequence of the first one.

The third statement follows by considering $A, B\in C$ and some indexings $(A_i\;:\; i\in J_A)$ and $(B_i\;:\; i\in J_B)$ such as per definition of $C$. Then consider the sequence $$U_i=\begin{cases}A_i& \text{if }i\in J_A\setminus J_B\\ B_i&\text{if }i\in J_B\setminus J_A\\ A_i\cap B_i&\text{if }i\in J_A\cap J_B\end{cases}$$ indexed by the finite set $J_A\cup J_B$ and notice that $A\cap B=\bigcap\limits_{i\in J_A\cup J_B} U_i$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ belongs to some $E_i$ then $A=A \cap X$ where $X$ is the whole space which belongs to $E_i$

So $A \in C$.

Thus $E_i \subseteq C,\forall i \in I$

Let $A_1,...A_m \in C$

Then $A_n=\bigcap_{j \in J_n} A_{i.j}$ where $J_n$ is finite,and $A_j \in E_j$

So $\bigcap_{n=1}^mA_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^m \bigcap_{j \in J_n} A_{i.j}=\bigcap_{i \in J_n \cup...\cup J_m} A_{i}$ where $A_i$ belongs to some $E_i$

So $C$ is a $\pi$-system.